# Array index out of bound exception while downloading elastic search index

Tags: shell, curl, elasticsearch, indexoutofboundsexception, kibana

I am trying to download complete elastic search index using:

```
curl -o output_filename -m 600 -GET 'http://ip/index/_search?q=*&size=7000000'.
```

But its giving error:

> {"error":"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[-131072]","status":500}

How can I download complete index data?

Answer (score 0):

[The scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) is what you're looking for, which supports proper pagination:

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data

It's the same `/_search` endpoint but additional gets passed the `?scroll=<timeout>` parameter.

Please be sure to understand what the timeout to e.g. `scroll=1m` means: it will keep alive your scroll context until you request the next batch/page.

Use the `scroll_id` from the response to request the next batch/page.